# mapping list of numbers to dictionary keys with multiple values

Tags: python

I will start with an example. let's say I have a dictionary such as:

```
d = {1:['A','B'],
     2:['C']}
```

and a list:

```
vals = [1,2]
```

I want to map these values in the list (vals) to all possible ones in the dictionary (d). so the output here should be two lists such as:

```
[[ 'A','C']['B','C']]
```

this is basically the problem I am facing now.  I thought I can do it with for loop but when we faced this dictionary and list of values,I couldn't do it using a for loop or even a nested loops:

```
d = {1:['A','B','C'] ,
     2:['D','E'],
     3:['F','G'],
     4:['I'] }

values = [1,2,3,4]
```

the output here should be:

```
[['A', 'D', 'F', 'I'], 
 ['A', 'D', 'G', 'I'],
 ['A', 'E', 'F', 'I'], 
 ['A', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
 ['B', 'D', 'F', 'I'], 
 ['B', 'D', 'G', 'I'],
 ['B', 'E', 'F', 'I'],
 ['B', 'E', 'G', 'I'], 
 ['C', 'D', 'F', 'I'],
 ['C', 'D', 'G', 'I'],
 ['C', 'E', 'F', 'I'],
 ['C', 'E', 'G', 'I']]
```

Comment: So, you are asking for all combinations of the specified indices, right?

Comment: @hawk_ could you please post any code you currently have and what it outputs? We'd like to see some effort on your end, and help point you in the right direction if possible rather than writing new code that you may have more difficulty following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html) `product()` for this. Just make a comprehension of the indexes you want to include and pass them to `product()`. If you are okay with tuples it's a nice one-liner:

```
import itertools

list(itertools.product(*(d[x] for x in values)))
```

results:

```
[('A', 'D', 'F', 'I'),
 ('A', 'D', 'G', 'I'),
 ('A', 'E', 'F', 'I'),
 ('A', 'E', 'G', 'I'),
 ('B', 'D', 'F', 'I'),
 ('B', 'D', 'G', 'I'),
 ('B', 'E', 'F', 'I'),
 ('B', 'E', 'G', 'I'),
 ('C', 'D', 'F', 'I'),
 ('C', 'D', 'G', 'I'),
 ('C', 'E', 'F', 'I'),
 ('C', 'E', 'G', 'I')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simple need working solution, use that of *Mark Meyer*, however if you are curious if it is doable via `for`s, answer is yes, following way:

```
d = {1:['A','B','C'] ,2:['D','E'],3:['F','G'],4:['I']}
for k in sorted(d.keys())[:-1][::-1]:
    d[k] = [(i+j) for i in d[k] for j in d[k+1]]
out = [tuple(i) for i in d[1]]
print(out)
```

gives:

```
[('A', 'D', 'F', 'I'), ('A', 'D', 'G', 'I'), ('A', 'E', 'F', 'I'), ('A', 'E', 'G', 'I'), ('B', 'D', 'F', 'I'), ('B', 'D', 'G', 'I'), ('B', 'E', 'F', 'I'), ('B', 'E', 'G', 'I'), ('C', 'D', 'F', 'I'), ('C', 'D', 'G', 'I'), ('C', 'E', 'F', 'I'), ('C', 'E', 'G', 'I')]
```

Note that this solution assumes that dict `d` is correct, i.e. its keys are subsequent numbers starting at `1` and all values are `list`s of one-letter `str`s. Now explanation: outer `for` is working on numbers from second greatest to `1`, descending, in this particular case: `3`,`2`,`1`. List comprehension is making "every-with-every" join (like `SQL CROSS JOIN`) of `k`-th list with `(k+1)`-th list and is effect is stored under current key `k`.
Finally I retrieve `d[1]` which is `list` of `str`s and convert it to `list` of `tuple`s compliant with requirements. If how this solution is working explanation is unclear for you please copy code snippet, add `print(d)` below `d[k] =` ... and observe what it prints.